# Discord/Youtube/Spotify 1mn latency (voice connexion SCTR issue) - Related to headset/firewall?

Tags: windows-10, audio, dns, youtube, discord

Since last Friday, my Windows 10 laptop has the following issues:

- 1mn latency to join a Discord channel (on Windows app)
- 1mn latency to start a Youtube video (on Chrome)
- 1mn latency to start a Spotify music

It seems there is an issue with the computer, one that doesn't seem to be related to the vendor (YouTube, Discord, Spotify). I tried various things (rebooting, reinstalling discord) but nothing has really worked so far.

At some point, the issue was gone, after disabling/enabling the Windows firewall. But as soon as I plugged my headset, it was back again. I wasn't able to make it work again, tried to flush DNS, use different DNS, etc.

Discord hangs with the "SCTR issue" until it works, 1mn or so later.

I don't know where the issue comes from. It doesn't seem to come from the apps, nor from the browser or browser extensions.

Funny thing, YouTube ads work just fine (they start immediately).

How can I pinpoint the origin of such issue?

Comment: Updating to Windows 11 while installing some "Realtech" update for audio seems to have fixed the issue, but I'll wait a few days before considering it "fixed". Also, no idea what could have been the issue.

Comment: What is "1mn"? Is it "1 minute"? mn is not an abbreviation I've ever seen before though I admit after using ms for milliseconds for years mn seems *odd*.

Comment: It's an usual abbreviation in France/French, I guess. And yes, it means "minutes".